# lightbox doesn't want to open image from folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lightbox2

I'm trying to setup lightbox plugin to load images from folder, but it don't want to open image. 
When I click on image and it trying open with lightbox, in terminal I get Routing error, no route matches.
Lightbox is working, tried with external image link, but it not working with images from folder.

This is what I have so far.

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <id class="gallery">
    <div class="row">
      <% @images.each do |image| %>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="<%= image %>" class="img-responsive" data-lightbox="my-images">
            <%= image_tag image, class: "img-responsive" %>
          </a>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </id>
</div>
```

**controller.rb**

```
  def gallery
    @images = Dir.chdir(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images')) do
      Dir.glob("galleria/landscape/*.jpg")
    end
  end
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require lightbox
//= require_tree .
```

**application.css**

```
 @import "lightbox";
```

**Source code:**

```
<a href="galleria/portrait/17-min.jpg" class="photo-hover img-responsive" data-lightbox="my-images"">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/galleria/portrait/17-min-ec4c03d557eb21edfdb115aaf9a69eab86e27b247385b8af3bb88a87cb398fd5.jpg" alt="17 min" />
</a>
```

Comment: Hey Kristis, it's going to be hard to answer this without more information. Are you getting any errors in your JS console? Can you confirm the `data-lightbox` attribute is showing on the `<img>` tags? Have you confirmed that the lightbox js lib is being requested in the Network or Sources tabs of your dev console?

Comment: Try changing  `@import "lightbox";` to `*= require lightbox` or try renaming `application.css` to `application.css.scss`

Comment: Hi coreyward, I'm not getting any errors. Data-lightbox attribute is showing, I  added source code to my question. Yes lightbox was requested in network tab

Comment: Pavan, thanks but same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct example**

Problem was with a href url.

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
  <div class="col-md-3 portrait">
    <a href='<%= "/images/#{image}" %>' data-lightbox="my-images">
      <%= image_tag image, class: "img-responsive" %>
    </a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```